# Matching the memory size of C# struct with C++ struct

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to create an automatic conversion from C# structs to unmanaged code in C++ and CUDA. Unfortunately I can't seem to create matching structures. The structures:

```
// C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct DebugComponent
{
    public float4 Float4;
    public float Float;
}

// C++
struct CPP_DebugComponent
{
    float4 Float4;
    float Float;
};
```

The size of the structure is calculated as 20 bytes using the C# call:

```
var size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf<DebugComponent>();
```

However in C++ using sizeof, the same structure is 32 bytes:

```
auto size = sizeof(CPP_DebugComponent);
```

I believe the difference originates from how the float4 structure is defined. The definition of float4 from CUDA aligns it with 16 bytes:

```
// C++
struct __device_builtin__ __builtin_align__(16) float4
{
    float x, y, z, w;
};
// For similar results without the CUDA definition, you can use:
// struct __align__(16) float4
```

Therefore adding 12 bytes of padding to the single float. In C#, there is no such alignment, leading the compiler to choose a packing of 4 bytes. For completeness, the float4 definition in C# (from ManagedCuda):

```
// C#
public struct float4
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
    public float w;
}
```

I know I can artificially recreate the correctly sized structure in C# by specifying the following attribute:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 32)]
 struct DebugComponent { ... }
```

But for automated code generation that would require knowing the sum of all types in the structure and some assumptions about packing and padding. It seems I can't widen the struct using the [StructLayoutAttribute.Pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack(v=vs.110).aspx).

I also know I can change the packing in C++ code by using for example:

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

But I'd rather avoid this solution since the padding leads to significant performance increases.

My question: can I mimic the behaviour of unmanaged padding/packing such that the C# structure aligns with the C++ structure in terms of memory size?

Are there a good alternatives to align the structures, keeping performance in mind?

All code samples above were run on Windows, Visual Studio 2017 and compiled on x64.

Comment: AFAIK the only portable tools you have are [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) and [aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage).

Comment: If you're mapping that to raw memory, `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf` is irrelevant; what does `sizeof(DebugComponent)` say?

Comment: sizeof(DebugComponent) (in unsafe code) is the same as the Marshal.Sizeof for this structure.

Comment: Couldn't you just fake padding by adding unused member vars in the beginning that consume 12 bytes in total?
Not that I would recommend that though, just saying...

Comment: That is indeed possible, however that would lead to the same problem: I would require to know the amount of space I need to fill up with variables.

Comment: Sure, the C# compiler knows beans about `__builtin_align__(16)`.  Nor does the CLR, and that is your nemesis.  Artificially growing the structure size is *not* a workaround, the point is that the start of the structure is at an address that is a multiple of 16.  Not possible, you can only get alignment to 4 in 32-bit code, to 8 in 64-bit code.  You can play tricks with Marshal.AllocHGlobal() (aligns to 8), allocating 8 more than necessary and adding 8 to the pointer if necessary.  Using C++/CLI is recommended so you can use `_aligned_malloc()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Padding and alignment of structures / structure members is AFAIK not part of the C++ standard and implementation dependent. Meaning, once you change your C++ compiler, you'll get a different layout (or might get). That's also one of the reasons that Nvidia garantes that CUDA works just with a few given compilers.

To get this code conversion running automatically, you'd need to mimic your C++ compiler in C# using the `StructLayout` options: Following the same rules as your C++ compiler. For the general case that's not impossible, but probably hard work to derive... For simple structures like the given one, on the other hand, it should be possible to derive the C++ compiler alignment rules. For instance one basic rule is, that the largest member determines the alignment of the entire structure.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the *best* method is to declare an array the size of the structure in the specification.  The C# or C++ object should copy elements out of the buffer into its data members.

This is most portable and can handle padding between C# and C++ members.  The C# and C++ classes are not good at mapping 1:1 with data formats because of padding, v-tables and other stuff.  The copying from the buffer can also deal with string classes and other non-POD types in a class.

Also research "serialization".